# Process WaitForExit() not waiting for Windows Explorer to close

Tags: vb.net, explorer, waitforexit

The code below is my attempt to open Windows Explorer, then wait for the user to close it, before continuing with the program.

This works using Notepad.exe but not Exlorer.exe

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim newProc As Diagnostics.Process
    'newProc = Diagnostics.Process.Start("Notepad.exe") 'This works
    newProc = Diagnostics.Process.Start("Explorer.exe") 'This does not work
    newProc.WaitForExit()
    MsgBox("Continue Processing")
```

End Sub

Thanks for your help

Comment: It is already open.  Explorer is a *singleton* process.  You did not ask it anything to do so it quickly terminates again without seeing anything change.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why my code does not work.
Is there any way in which I can detect when the user closes the Explorer window / instances that the program opened?